# How can I select all rows with value found in any column?

Tags: python-polars

I am a newbie to polars and have a very few knowledge in pandas.

pandas df

```
     a   b    c
0  Yes  No   No
1   No  No   No
2  Yes  No  Yes
```

polars df

```
│ a   ┆ b   ┆ c   │
│ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ str ┆ str ┆ str │
╞═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ Yes ┆ No  ┆ No  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ No  ┆ No  ┆ No  │
├╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Yes ┆ No  ┆ Yes │
└─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

In pandas, i can execute this and outputs as expected: `pd_df.iloc[pd.np.where(pd_df[pd_df.columns.to_list()].eq('Yes').any(1))].drop_duplicates()`.

```
     a    b    c
0  Yes    No   No
2  Yes    No  Yes
```

I'd like to know how can I get same output with polars. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `pl.fold()` for that. Check the last example [in the docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.fold.html#polars.DataFrame.fold)

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
...     {
...         "a": [False, False, True],
...         "b": [False, True, False],
...     }
... )
>>> df.fold(lambda s1, s2: s1 | s2)
shape: (3,)
Series: 'a' [bool]
[
        false
        true
        true
]
```

Comment: thanks.. i think i found the syntax. `pl_df.filter(pl.any(pl.col(pl_df.columns) == 'Yes'))`

Comment: Nice! some syntactic sugar: you can also use `pl.col("*")` to select all columns.

Comment: thanks Moritz, will definitely use that!

Comment: Note that even more succint is to use `pl.all()` rather than `pl.col("*")`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question. I've used [`pl.any_horizontal`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.any_horizontal.html#polars.any_horizontal) expression in filter.

```
pl_df.filter(pl.any_horizontal(pl.col('*') == 'Yes'))
```

Credits to Moritz for `'*'` replacement for `pl_df.columns`.

Edit: Updated to use new `any_horizontal` for column-wise, as `any` now acts within a column.

Comment: `pl_df.col("*")` should be `pl.col("*")` I think?

Comment: FYI, you can use `df.filter(pl.any(pl.all() == "Yes"))` which is a little more idiomatic polars.